# impossible to install a intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I downloaded the ultimate version of IntelliJ from the official website and when I do `./idea.sh` in the `.. /bin` directory of the file I get this error message in the terminal:

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /root/.jetbrains/jetbrains-agent-v3.2.0.de72.619 Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument`

I don't know if I am supposed to have a `.jetbrains` file in my repersonel if so why I don't have it and if not how to get it?

Cordially...

Answer (score 0):

What's the environment of your machine and I do not think you need to care about how to get `.jetbrains` manually by yourself. I've `installed` a IntelliJ idea on Ubuntu18.04, it works well. You can try run it **as an administrative**, also you can go to `./bin` folder and then run `./idea.sh` rather than `../bin` folder

btw, as I said `install`, it does not indicate we need to compile it and get some executable binary file to run it. It's a green software that contains anything you need, you can run it directly

Comment: I am under debian and I do all the operations in root

Comment: if so, please go to `./bin` folder and then try it again.

Comment: This is what I did

Comment: have you ever tried this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004330860--Resolved-PhpStorm-2019-2-won-t-start, maybe also this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519

Comment: yes I went through all these answers on the forum except that no problem is similar to mine so the solutions do not apply directly to me

Answer (score 0):

The `Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /root/.jetbrains/jetbrains-agent-v3.2.0.de72.619` error indicate that there is a problem with the distribution you have downloaded. It was corrupted or modified improperly.

Re-download it from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download and install into a new empty directory.
You can also try deleting the IDE's [config](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory) and [system](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory) directories.